# Yii Session Variables and Memcached

Tags: yii, memcached, session-variables

I am building a forum website using Yii PHP framework . I am also using Memcached for session maintenance and for storing some data objects .

For every user request I have to get some user information to check some thing ( to check if he is member of the particular group or not and also other checks )

So the two approaches what I am planing are

1) Don't store any thing in the session other than the user id and after user session established get the object from memcached and check it  - Here one user object and two calls to memcached server
( One is session call and other to get user object)

2) Store all the required user information in the session using **setState** method . After successful login user gets the information from session object and checks it . Here there are two user objects one in memcached and one in user session ( of course this again stores in memcached)  . But I feel when the session establishes with one call we get all the required details of the user ( really is this the case ?)

Not sure what is the best approach  . Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a perfomance perspective it makes no difference, because you also save the sessions in memached (that's at least what you said). So it's most logical to use the session for this kind of information. Otherwhise you'd have to create and store unique cache keys for each user - which kind of reinvents what the session already does for you.

Comment: Thank You Mike for your response . I think I forgot to mention any way I am storing user object in memcached for other reasons ( to compare with other users like are they friends or are they are in the same group ) . But as you said  looks like its better to store in session object ,even though the object is duplicated . I tested with couple of users and I see session object stores in the server and don't need to memcached to get the info again . If I don't store in session it became too many calls to memcached . Of course again as you said it won't make any performance difference .